# ASP.NET MVC Set the posted value to dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, caching, model-view-controller, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 ddlist for my app.I want to show selected values after submitting the page.The sumbit return the View() which is also same page.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DatabaseNames")
@Html.DropDownList("TableNames")
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check/button>


 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DatabaseNames").select2();
        $("#TableNames").select2();
    });
```

//CONTROLLER

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Profiles(FormCollection form)
    {   
       return View();
    }
```

I want to set selected values to this dropdownlists after submiting the page.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from FormCollection & return in ViewBag

Prepare the **SelectListItems**, where you can set **Selected** property  as below & send to view through ViewBag

```
 List<SelectListItem> dropdownItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
    dropdownItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Item 1", Selected = false });
    dropdownItems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Item 2", Selected = true });
```

Then in View retrieve **dropdownItems** & render as below

```
@Html.DropDownList("elementName", dropdownItems);
```

Comment: Yes I can get this value and add it to ViewBag. but how can I give this value as a selected